# What is Stamper negotiating for in his salary?

Tags: house-of-cards

In episode 3x05 of House of Cards, Stamper is negotiating his salary with Dunbar. His final negotiation is for "One point on the ad buy(?)" He accepts "No points. 
But I'll do a hundred thousand win bonus if we get the nomination."

What is the "Ad buy" that Stamper is negotiating for? Google seems to be of no help on this phrase!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By *point* he means one percentage (he wanted *three points* in their earlier conversation).
By *ad-buy* he means Dunbar's campaign spending.

He would like to receive a percentage of her campaign spending as part of his payment.

Note that Frank uses the same expression in this episode:

> And even so, we need more than ad-buys. We need... We need the philosophy behind it. We need something of substance. We need something... We need something that will capture the imagination. Either of you play Monument Valley?